# I'm using Discord.js and getting "Declaration or Statement expected" errors in the following code:

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm getting those errors on the closing `)};`. Without the encompassing `client.on('message', message => {` arrow function, the `message.channel.send` doesn't work (not declared ?)

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let failCounter = require('./commands/pendu_deviner');
    let mot = require('./commands/pendu_mot');
    let motClone = require('./commands/pendu_mot');
    if(failCounter = 11) {
        message.channel.send('Vous n\'avez pas réussi à trouver le mot !');
        message.channel.send(`Le mot était: ${mot.toString().replace(',', '')}`);
        }
    if(motClone = mot){
        message.channel.send('Vous avez deviné le mot; vous avez gagné !');
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. You have to match the closing brackets in reverse order they are opened. In other words, if you open one, close the nearest one first. Then deal with the block opened before that one, and so on.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    ...
});
```

Swap the curly brace and the parenthesis and you'll be set.

Comment: Well that's time that I'll never get back. Thank you for solving my problem, you prevented a major headache !